# cakephp string field used to create checkboxes

Tags: arrays, cakephp, checkbox

I'm using cakephp 2.1 and let me tell you: I just love it.
In my form I have a field that can have multiple answers (checkboxes).
I don't want to create a database field for each option, nor use an HABTM.

Update:

Since I needed several sets of flags, I went the $hasAndBelongsToMany way. (allos to add new flags without fixing the code but editing a table (eg. via phpmyadmin).

1.- Made a table/model for each set of flags I need:

2.- In my main model, declared the relation to each:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Sample','Format','Report','Openend','Dataproce','Prefield');
```

3.- In my main Controller, populated an array per table to use:

```
$openends = $this->Project->Openend->find('list', array(
                    //'order' => 'name'
            ));
```

4.- And use the arrays in the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Dataproce', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'size' => 2));
```

===  Old question starts here; correct answer worked for only one set of flags ===

I'd like to save a string and use it to to magically create a group of checkboxes that belong to a single data field.

I'm in the middle of it already.

my view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('pr_reports', array('type' => 'select',
                             'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                             'options' => array('0' => 'Interrnal',
                                                '1' => 'Disposition',
                                                '2' => 'Web Disposition',
                                                '3' => 'Marginal',
                                                '4' => 'Custom')))
```

my controller add method, before saving

```
        // Used serialize() to convert the array to string
        $dataString = serialize($this->request->data['Project']['pr_reports']);
        $this->request->data['Project']['pr_reports'] = $dataString;
```

The string is being saved allright (encoded it seems but is ok: a:5:{i:0;s)

My question is how would I go when editing the record in order for the checkboxes to check themselves accordingly? That is, where do I unserialize() the string field and handle this on the edit view?

Is there a better way for this?

Thank you very much for any help.

Carlos García

==== After solution, troubles to have more than one field with a different set of flags
data is only saved for one field, ignoring the other ====

Hello;
For one field on the table it works just fine as noted;
I'm having a hard time using another field (separate set of flags).
It seems only one behaviour is attached; I was wondering if I should attach them  differently.

my fields:

```
pr_data_format` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
pr_report_format` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

my controller

```
$this->Project->Behaviors->attach('Bitmasked', array('mappedField'=>'pr_data_formats', 'bits'=>'Project::pr_data_formats'));
$this->Project->Behaviors->attach('Bitmasked', array('mappedField'=>'pr_report_formats', 'bits'=>'Project::pr_report_formats'));
```

my model

```
        const STATUS_ASCII = 1;
        const STATUS_SPSS = 2;
        const STATUS_EXCEL = 4;
        const STATUS_CUSTOM = 8;

        public static function pr_data_formats($value = null) {
            $options = array(
                self::STATUS_ASCII => __('ASCIId'),
                self::STATUS_SPSS => __('SPSSBd'),
                self::STATUS_EXCEL => __('Exceld'),
                self::STATUS_CUSTOM => __('Customd'),
            );
            return parent::enum($value, $options);
        }                    


        const REP_ASCII = 1;
        const REP_SPSS = 2;
        const REP_EXCEL = 4;
        const REP_CUSTOM = 8;

        public static function pr_report_formats($value = null) {
            $options = array(
                self::REP_ASCII => __('ASCIIr'),
                self::REP_SPSS => __('SPSSBr'),
                self::REP_EXCEL => __('Excelr'),
                self::REP_CUSTOM => __('Customr'),
            );
            return parent::enum($value, $options);
        }
```

my view

```
echo $this->Form->input('pr_data_formats', array('options' => Project::pr_data_formats(), 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
echo $this->Form->input('pr_report_formats', array('options' => Project::pr_report_formats(), 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Just can't figure it out, tried:

```
$this->Project->Behaviors->attach('Bitmasked', array('mappedField'=>'pr_report_formats', 'bits'=>'Project::pr_report_formats'), array('mappedField'=>'pr_data_formats', 'bits'=>'Project::pr_data_formats'));
```

but no use, only one field is updated.

Can you help? We'll use some 4 or 5 flagsets.

Thank you so much.

Carlos

Comment: this looks nothing like you were supposed to do ;) the IDs are not 2^x (1,2,4,8,...) and you shouldnt manually serialize. I never tested two different checkboxes, though. but it should be able to make it work somehow.

Comment: I have it working with one field just fine; only now I duplicated the whole thing to have another field with some other flags. Are you saying that it can only be used with 1 field on the table and not 2 or more? You mention I shouldn't manually serialize.... I don't see where.  I's really appreciate any help.   Thanks !!

Comment: Update:
Since I needed several sets of flags, I went the $hasAndBelongsToMany way. (allows to add new flags without fixing the code but editing a table (eg. via phpmyadmin). Thank you so much Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a proper way to do this is using a behavior. this keeps your model clean and can be applied to several models simply by putting this in your model:

```
public $actsAs = array('MyBehavior');
```

now, for serializing I use my Jsonable Behavior:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/07/05/introducing-two-cakephp-behaviors/
it basically makes your input array a storable string on save and the string back to an array on read. you could easily adjust this to your needs.

BUT for what you want to do with multiple checkboxes there is even a better thing - bitmasks. I developed a so called Bitmasked behavior - you would need to use 1,2,4,8,... but other than that its the same thing:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/26/bitmasked-using-bitmasks-in-cakephp/
I use it exactly for the same thing.

Comment: Mark, Thank you so much.  I've read your blog and it seems like a perfect solution. I've put BitmaskedBehavior.php on /Model/Behavior folder. Then added `public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable','Bitmasked');` to my model and `$this->Project->Behaviors->attach('Bitmasked', array('mappedField'=>'pr_reports'));` to my controller.   I get error "Bits  not found".  I'm new to cakephp, Would you be kind enough to add on the steps to have it working? I mean, put this here, put this there sort of help.  Dont't get me wrong, I do my homework.   Please Help. Thank you again.

Comment: if you declared it globally via $actsAs you don't need to attach it dynamically ;) once is fine. you also need to pass the bitmask values to your behavior (using bitmask property). so if you declared them as my enums in a static method `reportTypes`, you should pass `'bits'=>'Project::reportTypes'` to the behavior declaration in `$actsAs = array('Bitmasked'=>array(...))`.

Comment: Thank you Mark; I think I’m almost there.
I’m getting:
'Fatal error: Call to undefined method AppModel::enum() in C:\wamp\www\dev.opm.asc\app\Model\project.php' 
Because I’m not sure how to do define enum.

Comment: Thank you Mark; I think I’m almost there.I’m getting:'Fatal error: Call to undefined method AppModel::enum() in ...\app\Model\project.php. Because I’m not sure how to do define enum. You mentioned the need to define MyModel::enum by extending my MyModel or by putting it into your AppModel manually..._ So in my model I put -from your "Static enums" blog entry-: ' public static function enum($value, $options, $default = '') {if ($value !== null) {if (array_key_exists($value, $options)) { ..etc...} Could you please elaborate a bit on how should I define MyModel::enum? Thanks a lot !

Comment: careful - it should be Project.php (the casing matters - always). also, you have been on the right track - if you copy it into your AppModel your model should extend this AppModel then. it is fairly simple once you understand how inheritance works.

Comment: Great! I put the enum in AppModel (return parent::enum makes more sense now). My field is tinyint and record on database displays 0 Zero! However, bits from checkbox do get stored. I was expecting to see a value in db. I guess I'll deal with it when/if need to search, for the time being this does the job, as I can "group" a bunch of flags.  Thank you so much !

Comment: Hello;
For one field on the table it works just fine as noted;
I'm having a hard time using another field (separate set of flags)
It seems only one behavior is attached; I was wondering if I should attach them  differently.   Updated the question to show some code. Can you please help?  Thanks !!!